# Formula to Average UPTO current row in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of values where I want to create an expanding average with an increasing index as shown in the screenshot below. I am able to do this manually by reselecting the cells with every row. Is there a formulaic way I can do this so that I can just click and drag the formula?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just realized that I asked the dumbest question in the history of stackoverflow (for excel at least).
I guess I could just pin column B2 and drag the rest.
Like `AVERAGE($B2$:B3)` and then just drag the formula.

Comment: Nah, there's no dumb questions.  :)